# let user create more elements on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I would like to know if there is anyway for a user to add to the elements of a html5 webpage? For example, is there anyway that they can add a paragraph or image to an existing webpage that wasn't there before?

eg.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p class=”pClass”>This is in a paragraph.</p>

    **//would it be possible for a user to insert several paragraphs here with the click of a button or something?**


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If your intention is to allow users to add content, you'd normally use wiki software like [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) for this. If not - [what are you after](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Yes, here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vTKGh/

Comment: @Yve It depends on what you're attempting to do. Do you want to provide them with a textbox and let that value be the contents of the paragraph?

Comment: @Yve Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vTKGh/1/

Comment: @Yve Oh, sorry, I don't know why I thought you were the OP... oops :)

Comment: Hello all, @Ian thanks for the response, that was basically what I was looking for:) if possible an answer to Yve would be useful as the intent is to allow users to add and edit the content of new paragraphs, but the answer here is sufficient to figure out the rest of my program:)

Comment: @Yve Sorry, I left after my last comment. Then today I made up a more full example and posted as an answer. I appreciate your comments and for creating the other question for me to answer, but hopefully my answer here helps the OP :)

Answer (score 2):

I probably went a little too far with making this, but I always like creating these little examples. Here's what I came up with. Start with this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<button id="btn1">Add Item</button>
<hr />
<div id="targetArea"></div>
```

And this CSS:

```
p.editable input.editor,
p.editable input.action,
p.editable em.escape {
    display: none;
}

p.editable input.action {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

p.editable em.escape {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 8px;
}

p.editable:hover input.action {
    display: inline;
}

p.editable.editing span.text {
    display: none !important;
}

p.editable.editing input.editor,
p.editable.editing input.action,
p.editable.editing em.escape {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

And use this JavaScript:

```
var textProp = "textContent" in document.createElement("div") ? "textContent" : "innerText";

function strTrim(str) {
    if (!str) {
        str = "";
    }
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);   
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    }
}

function editableClickHandler(e) {
    var actionButton, pNode, myText, myEditor;

    actionButton = this;
    pNode = actionButton.parentNode;
    myText = pNode.querySelector("span.text");
    myEditor = pNode.querySelector("input.editor");

    if (actionButton.value === "Edit") {
        actionButton.value = "Done";
        pNode.className += " editing";
        myEditor.setAttribute("data-original-val", myText[textProp]);    // Save current value in case of canceling
        myEditor.value = myText[textProp];
    } else {
        actionButton.value = "Edit";
        pNode.className = "editable";
        myText[textProp] = myEditor.value;
    }
}

function escapeCheckHandler(e) {
    var keyCode, pNode, myEditor, myText, myActionButton;

    e = e || window.event;    // Normalize event
    keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode;    // Normalize keycode

    if (keyCode === 27) {    // Escape key
        pNode = this.parentNode;
        myEditor = pNode.querySelector("input.editor");
        myText = pNode.querySelector("span.text");
        myActionButton = pNode.querySelector("input.action");

        pNode.className = "editable";
        myText = myEditor.getAttribute("data-original-val");
        myActionButton.value = "Edit";
    }
}

function addClickHandler() {
    var target, curInput, curInputVal, newP, newText, newEditor, newActionButton, newEscapeInfo;

    curInput = document.getElementById("txt1");
    curInputVal = strTrim(curInput.value);

    if (!curInputVal) {
        alert("Must provide actual text");
        return;
    }

    target = document.getElementById("targetArea");
    newP = document.createElement("p");
    newText = document.createElement("span");
    newEditor = document.createElement("input");
    newActionButton = document.createElement("input");

    newP.className = "editable";

    newText.className = "text";
    newText[textProp] = curInputVal;
    newP.appendChild(newText);

    newEditor = document.createElement("input");
    newEditor.type = "text";
    newEditor.className = "editor";
    addEvent(newEditor, "keyup", escapeCheckHandler);
    newP.appendChild(newEditor);

    newActionButton.type = "button";
    newActionButton.className = "action";
    newActionButton.value = "Edit";
    addEvent(newActionButton, "click", editableClickHandler);
    newP.appendChild(newActionButton);

    newEscapeInfo = document.createElement("em");
    newEscapeInfo.className = "escape";
    newEscapeInfo[textProp] = "(Press Escape to Cancel Editing)";
    newP.appendChild(newEscapeInfo);

    curInput.value = "";
    target.insertBefore(newP, target.firstChild);
}

function loadHandler() {
    addEvent(document.getElementById("btn1"), "click", addClickHandler);
}

addEvent(window, "load", loadHandler);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8K3pN/2/

The use of `addEvent` helps to bind event handlers more consistently across browsers.

What happens overall, is when you fill in the textbox and click the button, it adds a `<p>` (with some child elements) to the target area. Depending on the state of the `p`, certain things are hidden/shown (with the CSS). And depending on the state of the button is clicked (Edit/Done), certain things happen. I added in the ability to press the Escape key to "cancel" editing (instead of adding another button).

Again, I know this was probably too much, but I hope this helps you understand how this all can work together!

Answer (score 0):

AS the others have said we're not sure what you want to accomplish, but you can add elements to a document from JavaScript using the `document.createElement()` function. You could provide a text box to enter the text and then call a JS function add a paragraph to to your div.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you had in mind?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var count = 1;
        function newPara() {
            var new_p = document.createElement('p');
            new_p.setAttribute('class','pClass');
            new_p.setAttribute('id','new_para_'+ count++);

            var newContent = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('content').value);
            new_p.appendChild(newContent);

            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].insertBefore(new_p,document.getElementById('create'));
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p class=”pClass”>This is in a paragraph. <br/></p>


    <div id="create">
    <textarea id="content"> </textarea>
    <button onclick="newPara();"> Create </button>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```